# How to upload mp3 file to Firebase storage using Angularfire2?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm trying to upload mp3 file to firebase storage using angularfire2 in my ionic2 application,

> this file is created using ionic-native/file plugin using createFile(path,fileName,replace) where the doc is [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/).

And this is the code:

```
this.file.createFile(cordova.file.externalDataDirectory, this.fileName, true).then((result) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result,null,2),"result")
                this.files = result;
                this.mediaPlugin = new MediaPlugin(cordova.file.documentsDirectory + this.fileName);
            }, (e) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2))
            })
```

this code is working well the file is created!

After that I wanna put this file to Firebase storage, I tried this code but that didn't work:

```
let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const voiceRef = storageRef.child(`voices/${this.fileName}.wav`);
    voiceRef.put(this.files.filesystem).then(snap=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(snap));
    },(e)=>{
      console.log(JSON.stringify(e,null,2));
    })
```

I got an error that told:

[image: firebase error]

I think the error is from the put method parameter, I don't know what i should put in this parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [specifying the content type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata) before uploading the file:

```
let metadata = {
  contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
};
voiceRef.put(this.files.filesystem, metadata).then(...)
```